# All possible Intersections of cells in cell array : MATLAB.

Tags: matlab, combinations

Consider a cell array ,

```
H = [ {N1x1} {N2x1} {N3x1} ...{Nmx1} ]
```

*How does get (efficiently) all pairwise intersections of these cells?*

Comment: By intersection you mean the common elements, right?

Comment: Yeah. All possibilities like `intersect(H{1},H{2})`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how efficient this will be.

```
N = numel(H);
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:N);
result = arrayfun(@(n) intersect(H{ii(n)},H{jj(n)}), 1:N^2, 'uni', 0);
result = reshape(result,N,N);
```

*Example*:

```
H = {[1 2 3], [2 3], [4 5]};
```

gives

```
result = 
    [1x3 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x0 double]
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x0 double]
    [1x0 double]    [1x0 double]    [1x2 double]
>> result{1,1}
ans =
     1     2     3
>> result{1,2}
ans =
     2     3
>> result{1,3}
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0

[..]
```

This also works if `H` is a multidimensional cell array.

---

You could also use two `for` loops. Then you could save half operations explotiing the symmetry of the result.

Comment: Hey Luiz. I tried your code for H with 6 cells. 6C2 = 15 so I should get 15x1 cell array right? 
But I'm getting a 6x6 cell array.

Comment: See example in edited answer. Why do you mean "6C2"?

Comment: @Nishanth Try this modified version of Luis's code  - `combs = sortrows(combnk(1:numel(H),2)), result = arrayfun(@(n1) intersect(H{combs(n1,1)},H{combs(n1,2)}), 1:size(combs,1), 'uni', 0)`

Comment: @Nishanth Now I got what you denote by 6C2. Yes, that's what I meant in my comment regarding the use of two loops to save operations